# thread 'main' panicked at 'Not in workspace, cli/src/lib.rs note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-client

[image]

The version of anchor i'm using is 0.29.0

I tried to set RUST_BACKTRACE=1 in the terminal by `export RUST_BACKTRACE=1`. I got the following error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This error says you're not in the anchor workspace, aka the directory of your project. The fix is just to double check you're in the correct directory, i.e. the one that has your `Anchor.toml` file (and other files) in it.